# Java Hibernate. Задача: создать сервер возможностью регистрации пользователей и сохранять их в базу данных для сохранения после перезапуска

Tags: java, hibernate

Сервер работает корректно, имею проблемы с сохранением в БД. Использую H2. Есть два сервлета - на регистрацию и вход. При регистрации сохраняю нового пользователя в базу данных. После перезапуска сервера должен происходить вход в ранее созданную учетную запись. При запуске создается таблица users (hibernate_hbm2ddl_auto параметр create), после регистрации добавляются пользователи, но после перезапуска таблица создается заново без сохраненных записей. Пробовал параметр update - БД не создается в начале. Как сделать так, чтобы при запуске сервера программа проверяла наличие базы данных?

```
    private Configuration getH2Configuration() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(UsersDataSet.class);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.h2.Driver");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:h2:./h2db");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "admin");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "admin");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        return configuration;
    }
```

Comment: Вроде как H2 по умолчанию только во время работы приложения существует. Если надо, чтобы она сохранялась при перезапусках, надо это в конфиге прописать. Покажите что у вас в `spring.datasource.url` прописано

Comment: Spring не использую

Comment: Дело не в спринг. Как конфигурируете доступ к БД? jdbc url покажите.

Comment: Конфигурацию задаю методом, в описании добавил